# What user and password in phpmyadmin will I use in cpanel?

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

This is my very first time uploading a website. now I'm having a problem with my hosting which is CPANEL.

I'm using the code

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "exampledb";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

?>
```

for my database connection.

Now my problem is what code should I put in servername? instead of localhost?
and same to the username root and password?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
// localhost is fine or else you need to keep your server IP.you can find in cpanel.
$servername = "localhost";

// if you are using database in some other server you should provide IP
// you need to create a user with required privileges then need to provide username/password 
// root also fine but better create a user
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Here you need to mention which DB you want use for your application.
$db = "exampledb";
```

Comment: can I use domain name instead of IP?

Comment: I see IP in access host. Is that what I need to use?

Comment: yes....... checking purpose ping your domain in command line.you wil get IP

Comment: @finwe: is there anything wrong in my post. please mention.

Comment: @Arvin Jason Cabrera

Comment: Nothing. I did not vote for down. and I can't vote because I don't have enough post.

Answer (score 1):

On the hosting site in cpanel they normally give you the server name that you can use, the password you will need to create a db user also on cpanel, this will be your user name and password.

Comment: So you create your database and you can also create a database user, this will be you user and password.